# Communication between 2 windows application over UDP sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, winsockets

I am writing some code in C, which uses UDP sockets and I want to test it. What I basically want is to run two Windows applications (simply said, 2 .exe files) which would share some bytes between each other by using Winsockets. Could someone tell which ports and which IP addresses (simply broadcast) I could use for that matter? Or I need to use a Linux virtual machine and make a communication between a Windows and Linux application.

Cheers

Comment: Uhhhh.... use the IP of the machine you are attempting to communicate with.... and use the port your service binds to...?

Comment: As you can read, I am trying to have a communication between two Windows application, meaning they are not machines and don't have their own IP addresses; Second, I am using the UDP sockets, meaning there is binding;

Comment: Can you not just run them on the same box using localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: As Martin has stated, you can just use `127.0.0.1` which is a loopback address. Also,[UDP does allow port binding](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/listen_for_and_receive_udp_datagrams_in_c.html#idp16960). Each application should setup their own receivers to listen for UDP traffic from the other, or a broadcast address. If you design it to use UDP the services do not even need to live on the same host. If these were two services both running on the same Linux host you could use [unix sockets](https://serverfault.com/a/124518/146878) which allow interprocess communication without the TCP stack.

Comment: Your computer has an IP address, and you can use any port you want if it's not already in use. You can also use 127.0.0.1 which means "this computer" (regardless of which computer you use it on), then you don't need to know its actual IP address.

Comment: Martin James, Matt Clark, immibis Thanks that works. Actually both the loopback address and the local address of my PC work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to communicate with two different `exe` files either on same machine or different machines.For that you would have to write two different code for a `client` and a `server` using `winsock`.Run the server first and then run client, connect client with the server giving `ip address` of your machine and any port on which server is listening (which should be chosen greater than 5000).

Go through the following link for better understanding of implementation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for effort. However, as you can see I was talking about the UDP connection, not TCP/IP. The problem got solved, thanks anyway though